# Finding an upper limit on a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, taylor-expansion, upper-lower-bounds

I'm tasked with finding a smallest constant $c$ so that for a function $f\in C^4([0,1])$ and $x,y\in[0,1]$:
$$\left\vert\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}-\frac{f'(x)+f'(y)}{2}\right\vert\le c\vert x-y\vert ^2\max_\limits{\xi\in[0,1]}\vert f'''(\xi)\vert$$
Since this is an excercise I was given on the Topic of Taylor series, my first thought was making use of Taylor's theorem and somehow set the upper bound using the Lagrange remainder but I'm not quite sure that's the way to go. Alternatively I thought about using the fact, that $f(x)$ is lipschitz continuous. Any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A hint would be to find the Taylor expansion of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ at $y$, then use the Lagrange remainder for the third derivative term.

Comment: @player3236 Thanks for the hint, I played around a bit with it, but I'don seem to get anywhere. Could you maybe elaborate on your idea, please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x \ne y$, there exists $\xi_1, \xi_2$ between $x,y$ such that:

\begin{align}
f(x)&=f(y)+f'(y)(x-y)+\frac {f''(y)}2(x-y)^2+\frac{f'''(\xi_1)}6(x-y)^3\\
f'(x)&=f'(y)+f''(y)(x-y)+\frac {f'''(\xi_2)}2(x-y)^2\end{align}

Substituting:

\begin{align}&\quad\left\vert\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}-\frac{f'(x)+f'(y)}{2}\right\vert
\\&=\left\vert\frac{f'(y)(x-y)+\frac {f''(y)}2(x-y)^2+\frac{f'''(\xi_1)}6(x-y)^3}{x-y}-\frac{2f'(y)+f''(y)(x-y)+\frac {f'''(\xi_2)}2(x-y)^2}{2}\right\vert\\
\\&=\left\vert f'(y)+\frac {f''(y)}2(x-y)+\frac{f'''(\xi_1)}6(x-y)^2-f'(y)-\frac {f''(y)}2(x-y)-\frac {f'''(\xi_2)}4(x-y)^2\right\vert
\\&=\left\vert \frac{f'''(\xi_1)}6(x-y)^2-\frac {f'''(\xi_2)}4(x-y)^2\right\vert
\\&\le\left(\left\vert \frac{f'''(\xi_1)}6\right\vert+\left\vert\frac {f'''(\xi_2)}4\right\vert\right)(x-y)^2
\end{align}

Comment: Why don't we have to sum up to to the third derivative and add the fourth as the Lagrange remainder, instead of only summing up to the second and adding the third when describing f(x)? Same goes for f'(x)

Comment: We don't have a bound for the fourth derivative; on the contrary we are asked to bound the expression with $\max |f'''(\xi)|$.

Comment: @player3236 This only partially answer the question which is *finding a **smallest** constant $c$*. You need to prove that there is no lower constant than $1/6 + 1/4$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net How would one do this? Since we jump from two certain $\xi$ to $\max |f'''(\xi)|$ how can we find a smaller constant, without knowing the relation between the three $\xi$?

Comment: To do this, you need to find a map $f_0$ for which you have **equality** $\left\vert\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}-\frac{f'(x)+f'(y)}{2}\right\vert = c\vert x-y\vert ^2\max_\limits{\xi\in[0,1]}\vert f'''(\xi)\vert$ with the constant $c$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net is this really the only way of proving that it is the smallest constant? Seems very elaborate for such a seemingly small task. If I were unable to find such a map how would I continue from there, since I've only proven that 1/6 + 1/4 isn't the smallest constant.

Comment: I don't see another way. The answer above proves that $c \le 1/6+1/4$. Finding such a map $f_0$ would prove that indeed $c = 1/6 + 1/4$. By the way it is not even sure that $1/6 + 1/4$ is the smallest $c$!

Comment: @Carlo In fact the smallest constant is not $1/6 + 1/4$ but $1/12$. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the smallest constant for which the inequality holds is $c = \frac{1}{12}$.

For the proof, consider the map

$$\varphi(t) =f(x) - f(t) +\frac{t-x}{2}\left(f^\prime(t) + f^\prime(x)\right)-\frac{(t-x)^3}{12}A$$ where $A$ is such that $\varphi(y)=0$.

As $\varphi(x)=0$ [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem) ensures the existence of $c_1 \in (x,y)$ with $\varphi^\prime(c_1)=0$, i.e.
$$0 =  - f^\prime(c_1) +\frac{f^\prime(c_1) + f^\prime(x)}{2}+\frac{c_1-x}{2}f^{\prime\prime}(c_1)+\frac{(c_1-x)^2}{4}A.$$

Applying [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) to $f^\prime$ it exists $c \in (x,c_1)$ with

$$f^\prime(x) - f^\prime(c_1)=(x-c_1)f^{\prime\prime}(c_1) + \frac{(x-c_1)^2}{2} f^{\prime \prime \prime}(c).$$

The two equalities above imply $A=f^{\prime \prime \prime}(c)$. Using $\varphi(y)=0$ in the definition of $\varphi$ we get for $x \neq y$

$$\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} - \frac{f^\prime(x) + f^\prime(x)}{2}= -\frac{(x-y)^2}{12}f^{\prime \prime \prime}(c)$$ and therefore the desired inequality

$$\left\vert\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}-\frac{f^{\prime}(x)+f^{\prime}(y)}{2}\right\vert \le \frac{\vert x-y\vert ^2}{12}\max_\limits{\xi\in[0,1]}\vert f^{\prime \prime \prime}(\xi)\vert.$$

For $f(x) = x^3$, the inequality becomes an equality for all $x \neq y$, proving that $c=\frac{1}{12}$ is the smallest constant for which the inequality is valid.